# Instantiate an Object with curly braces C++

Tags: c++, object, initialization

I've read numerous explanations on initializing with braces:

```
PhoneNumber homePhone = {858, 555, 1234};
```

as well as

```
int x2 = val; // if val==7.9, x2 becomes 7 (bad)

char c2 = val2; // if val2==1025, c2 becomes 1 (bad)

int x3 {val}; // error: possible truncation (good)

char c3 {val2}; // error: possible narrowing (good)

char c4 {24}; // OK: 24 can be represented exactly as a char (good)

char c5 {264}; // error (assuming 8-bit chars): 264 cannot be 
               // represented as a char (good)
```

However, I've come across a bit of code here that I can't find an example on, perhaps I do not know the term so that I can google it:

```
auto ac1 = ArrayClass{};
```

I am used to doing

```
ArrayClass ac1 = new ArrayClass();
```

First of all is:

```
auto ac1 = ArrayClass{};
```

the same as

```
ArrayClass ac1 = ArrayClass{};
```

Secondly,

Am I only allowed to use braces if I used an initialization list in my constructor?

And lastly, if I have parameters, is the following correct?

```
auto ac1 = ArrayClass{1,4,"hi", true}
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 9):

This style of initialization is called *list-initialization*. You can read more on it at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization.

---

> I am used to doing
>
> ```
> ArrayClass ac1 = new ArrayClass();
> ```

That is not correct C++ syntax. You can use:

```
 ArrayClass* acPtr = new ArrayClass();
```

---

> First of all is:
>
> ```
> auto ac1 = ArrayClass{};
> ```
>
> the same as
>
> ```
> ArrayClass ac1 = ArrayClass{};
> ```

Yes, it is same.

---

> Secondly,
>
> Am I only allowed to use braces if I used an initialization list in my constructor?

Yes.

---

> And lastly, if I have parameters, is the following correct?
>
> ```
> auto ac1 = ArrayClass{1,4,"hi", true};
> ```

You can use that syntax if:

`ArrayClass` has at least four members, **and**
the first member can be initialized using `1`, **and**
the second member can be initialized using `4`, **and**
the third member can be initialized using `"hi"`, **and**
the fourth member can be initialized using `true`, **and**
any other remaining members can be value initialized.

You can read more about *value-initialization* at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization.

Comment: That linked documentation is as close to impossible for a C++ newbie to understand as can be humanly possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
auto ac1 = ArrayClass{};
```

allocates on the stack and the variable is automatically cleaned up when the stack goes away.

```
ArrayClass ac1 = new ArrayClass();
```

is invalid unless ArrayClass is typedef'd to be a pointer.  Regardless, new ArrayClass() allocates memory on the heap that must be explicitly cleaned up by calling `delete` on it.

> auto ac1 = ArrayClass{};
>
> the same as
>
> ArrayClass ac1 = ArrayClass{};

yes.